# How to create GString from String without "${str}" in Groovy

Tags: java, string, groovy, gstring

I have `String` variable from Java (for example, `str`), that stores some `GString` expression, lets say `"SELECT ${path} path FROM dual"`, it is absolutely dynamic string from user input, I can't know, how many `${}` will be there.

And I want not to use it in `sql.rows()` with evaluated `${path}` by current binding using `PreparedStatement`.

**The problem is:**

1. If I won't convert `str` to `GString` somehow, it will throw `SQLException`, because without `PreparedStatement` we need use quotes around `'${path}'`. But it is unsafe, and Groovy generates warnings (that we should use `PreparedStatement` and remove quotes).
2. If I will convert `str` to `GString` this way: `sql.rows("${str}")`, then Groovy will use absolutely wrong prepared statement that contains just `"?"`, of course, it won't work, I need statement: `"SELECT ? path FROM dual"`.

**The question is** how can we get `GString` from `String` without wrapping it with `"${}"`? Or how can we evaluate only first level of `GString` (only `str`, not `path`)? Or how can I solve this problem in the other way?

Thank you.

Comment: lots of examples are here: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2505;  but be sure to sanitize the queries or else you get yourself some SQL injection

Comment: @cfrick, this (not eval) examples doesn't work in my case, it violates at least one point in my "problem". eval examples doesn't work because my string have ',' chars and eval throws exception.

Comment: Can you make an example of a String that fails to eval and how the final GString is supposed to look like?

Comment: @blackdrag, fails to eval: `"SELECT '123' test\n, ${path} path FROM dual"`, final GString is supposed to look like: `"SELECT '123' test\n, ${path} path FROM dual"` (just like String, I need to convert it without any changes, for using in `sql.rows` (and without evaluation of `${path}` of course, because I need to use auto `sql.rows` prepared statement mechanics).

Comment: and why does there def gstring = Eval.me(/"str"/) not work?, I see no reason why the comma should lead to a problem, unless you evaluate directly. But this would be Eval.me(str) then

Comment: @blackdrag, because `Eval.me(/"str"/)` will eval in just `"str"` and `Eval.me(str)` will try to eval all words of `str`, (even `SELECT` etc) and if it contains `,`, then groovy will throw `groovy: 1: unexpected token: ,`. Can you just post tested code, which starts with `String str = 'SELECT '123' test\n, ${path} path FROM dual';` and ends with `sql.rows(GSTRING_FROM_STR)`? `'` quoutes around `String` is important.

Answer (score 0):

according to the information I suggest the following half solution:

```
def gsring = Eval.me('"'+str.replaceAll("\"","\\"")+'"')
```

it will replace all double quotes with escaped qutoes and then evaluates the whole thing as into a GString. This should work, as long as no double quotes are used in the value parts. gstring can be used then for the Sql. This solution is basically the same as the first two evaluate examples in GROOVY-2505. The important point missed by marshall is obviously that we need to wrap the string contents in quotes. A /"str"/ will of course just produce a string "str". If str is for example SELECT, then this would produce "str". What we want is '"'+str+'"', which will give "SELECT". It does have to be  double quotes, because we want the Eval call to evaluate the gstring parts, which is not available in a single quoted string.